# retriving CURTIME() from server by adding 3hrs and show it in PHP page

Tags: php, mysql

How can I retriving CURTIME() from server by adding 3hrs and show it in PHP page.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: CURTIME() sounds like MySQL - tag added.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to you can let MySQL handle the time arithmetic

```
SELECT Time(Now()+Interval 3 hour)
```

see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Answer (score 1):

in MySQL:

```
SELECT CURTIME()
```

Then in PHP:

```
// get the SQL query result in $curtime, then:
$t = strtotime( date('Y-m-d ') . $curtime );
$t = strtotime( "+3 hours", $t );
echo date( 'H:i:s', $t);
```

But if the time on the PHP server is the same, you could do that directly:

```
echo date( 'H:i:s', strtotime( '+3 hours' ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

The time calculation is done this way:

```
$unixTime = time() + 60 * 60 * 3;
echo gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', $unixTime);
```

If you intend to provide the time for a different time zone, though, you should have a look at the [DateTime class](http://de.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) in php.

**EDIT**

If you need to get the time from a mysql server, the `$unixTime` is calculated this way (Do not forget to insert error handling for the mysql functions):

```
$resultRow = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query('SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP() + 60 * 60 * 3'));
$unixTime = $resultRow[0];
```